# Triggering Cron job on AWS manually through sending a message from SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I setup cron job on Elasticbeanstalk using `cron.yaml` file and sqs run my tasks periodically. Is there a way to trigger a cron job manually through sqs platform so that for not-frequently running tasks I can easily test the results without waiting for the schedule itself? I tried to send a message to sqs queue attached to eb instance but can't set the http headers required for cronjob.